# Input shapes for multiclass LTSM classification model in tensorflow

Tags: neural-networks, python, lstm, tensorflow, keras

I am building a classifier for 7 classes where my array shapes are as follows:

```
X_train data shape - (171812, 384)
y_train data shape - (171812,)
X_test data shape - (37715, 384)
y_test data shape - (37715,)
```

my model is like this:

```
   # parameters 
input_dim= 10000 
max_length =384 
output_dim =128 DENSE_DIM = 32
DENSE_DIM = 32   
LSTM1_DIM = 32 
LSTM2_DIM = 16
WD = 0.001
FILTERS = 64 
   
   model_lstm = tf.keras.Sequential([
       tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim, output_dim, input_length=max_length),
   #    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, stateful=False, input_shape = ####(32,384,128)),
       tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(LSTM1_DIM, dropout=0.2, kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l2(WD), return_sequences=True)), 
       tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(LSTM2_DIM, dropout=0.2, kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l2(WD))),
       tf.keras.layers.Dense(DENSE_DIM, activation='relu'),     
       tf.keras.layers.Dense(7, activation='softmax') ])
   
   # Set the training parameters 
model_lstm.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                      optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), 
                      metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()])
                       
   
   model_lstm.summary()
Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_31 (Embedding)    (None, 384, 128)          1280000   
                                                                
bidirectional_67 (Bidirecti  (None, 384, 64)          41216     
onal)                                                           
                                                                
bidirectional_68 (Bidirecti  (None, 32)               10368     
onal)                                                           
                                                                
dense_108 (Dense)           (None, 32)                1056      
                                                                
dense_109 (Dense)           (None, 7)                 231       
                                                                
=================================================================
```

I am having ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 7) are incompatible when I run:

```
epochs = 12
batch_size = 250

history = model_lstm.fit(X_train, y_train,
          epochs=epochs,
          validation_data=(X_test, y_test),
          batch_size=batch_size)
```

What should I be changing?

Also I am using an embedding layer for this model with 3 parameters (input_dim, output_dim, input_length) and I do not understand why using an LTSM layer instead

```
tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, stateful=False, input_shape = (32,384,128))
```

does not have a compatible input shape? I thought input_shape should contain batch_size, no_features (384) and timesteps, so I put 3 parameters in?
it gives ValueError: Input 0 of layer "lstm_68" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, 32, 384, 128).

Thank you.